# How to manage long string in the text of a QPushButton?

Tags: qt

The text I want to write is to long to be seen in one line. How can the text be adapted at the size of the button and is displayed on more than one line.
[image: What I don't want to have]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Text` item give you the `WrapMode`. Refer [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#wrapMode-prop)

You can take this as an example: MyButton.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: buttonRect

    height: 40
    width: 200
    color: "#404040"
    radius: 5

    property alias buttonText: text
    signal clicked()

    Rectangle {
        id: maskRect
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "#575757"
        radius: buttonRect.radius
        visible: buttonMousearea.pressed
    }

    Text {
        id: text
        text: qsTr("Button")
        color: "white"
        width: parent.width
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        wrapMode: Text.Wrap
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: buttonMousearea
        anchors.fill: buttonRect
        hoverEnabled: true
        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
        onClicked: buttonRect.clicked()
    }

    states: [
        State {
            name: "hasMouse"
            when: buttonMousearea.containsMouse
            PropertyChanges {
                target: buttonRect
                color: "#6e6e6e"
            }
            PropertyChanges {
                target: buttonMousearea
                cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then use it like below

```
MyButton {buttonText.text: "something which is really longer than the button"}
```